# How to test with the "Quantum Internet"?

Tags: communication, quantum-networks

I want to test some ideas using the quantum internet. I know that is not widely available now. Can it be simulated? Are there any simulation systems which allow -

1. Entanglement
2. Testing states
3. Integration states in third-party systems (eg C++ programs)

The kind of tool would be useful, would basically confirm certain properties of the communications and how they could then be used in a classical layer e.g. for communications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a set of two packages in Mathematica called "Quantum Notation" and "Quantum Computing" for Wolfram Mathematica Environment, and here you can very well mimic all three considerations you are concerned with and much more in the usual Dirac Notation and Quantum Circuit Formalism. 
The link to the packages are as follows: 
http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/jose.luis.gomez/quantum/

You can also use the QET package for MATLAB if you are familiar with that environment:
http://www.qetlab.com/Main_Page

The only difference being that this will be performed on a classical computer and not really on a Quantum Interface. 
Since there is not really such a vast open source network for Quantum Computing, except a few like IBM-Q, the best option for my experience is to use the packages in Mathematica.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

[Reutter and Vicary](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.00966.pdf)

Features of teleportation, dense coding and secure key distribution are mimicked even without having an honest quantum internet.

The main idea is the groudit. That is a special type of groupoid where there certain bijections as sets given as extra data. That is for a given natural number $d$, think about $d$ finite groups all of cardinality $d$ and put them all together.

I have some Haskell you can use to play around with this concept if you want.

Comment: Yes please post the Haskell or put here the github name.

Comment: [Repo link](https://github.com/Cobord/Quantum-Computer-Things/tree/master/Quantum%20Networks) but forgot to go back to this part so not that much implemented

Comment: The example in the paper is $d=2$, but if you make $d$ larger, you can try to do something more secure.